# MVC EnumMember custom string

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, enums

I had this set of Enums for currency purpose

```
[DataContract]
public enum PaymentCurrency
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Canadian dollar.
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember(Value = "CA$")]
    CAD = 1,
}
```

When I want to display the particular item , for example CAD , I want it to show as "CA$" string . I tried it by assigning a value to it , it is not working and I haven't got much clue . Any ideas ? Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` argument of the `EnumMember` attribute is there for serialization. Not display purposes. See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx).

To get at that value you'd have to serialize it then parse the XML.

Another way is to write your own helper method and take advantage of C# built-in `DescriptionAttribute`:

```
public enum PaymentCurrency
{
  [DescriptionAttribute("CA$")]
  CAD,
  [DescriptionAttribute("US$")]
  USD,
  EURO
}
```

Then using your own helper methods in an `EnumUtils` class you could do this:

```
public class EnumUtils
{
  public static string stringValueOf(Enum value)
  {
    var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[]) fi.GetCustomAttributes( typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0].Description;
    }
    else
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
  }

  public static object enumValueOf(string value, Type enumType)
  {
    string[] names = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
    foreach (string name in names)
    {
      if (stringValueOf((Enum)Enum.Parse(enumType, name)).Equals(value))
      {
          return Enum.Parse(enumType, name);
      }
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("The string is not a description or value of the specified enum.");
  }
}
```